# AutoCAD VBA how to zoom in to a cell in an AutoCAD table

Tags: autocad

Is it possible to zoom into a specific cell in a table?
I have a table with text values in each cell and need to zoom in to each cell. Normally I can zoom into an object using the entity handle with `acZoomScaledRelative` and the bounding box max and min values. But with a table there are no text entity handles for the text in the cells.

Regards Tyke

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ActiveX [GetCellExtents](http://entercad.ru/acadauto.en/idh_table_getcellextents.htm) method to obtain an array of coordinates corresponding to the four corners of a table cell - this method also accounts for the possibility of merged cells.

Here is an example of an AutoLISP implementation that you may be able to port to VBA:

```
(defun cellextents ( obj row col / a b c d lst rtn )
    (if (= :vlax-true (vla-ismergedcell obj row col 'a 'b 'c 'd))
        (setq row a col c)
    )
    (setq lst (vlax-invoke obj 'getcellextents row col :vlax-true))
    (repeat 4 (setq rtn (cons (list (car lst) (cadr lst) (caddr lst)) rtn) lst (cdddr lst)))
    (reverse rtn)
)
```

Upon obtaining these coordinates, you can invoke the ZoomWindow method of the Application object to zoom to a window defined by the lower-left and upper-right coordinates.